# Using Firefox HTML source viewer in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, debugging, firefox

I want to view the HTML source of a web page, I've using ICSharpCode.TextEditor, Scintilla,... and they're all good. But, I have missed Firefox HTML source viewer.

I wonder if I can use Mozilla ActiveX Control to open the source viewer or is there a command line argument that make Firefox open it? Thanks!

Comment: I am unsure what you mean here, are you trying to edit the source of an asp.net page, if so viewing the source of the page won't really help as asp.net is interpreted.

Comment: I don't want to edit the source of an ASP.NET page, I just want to view the HTML source (just like the way you press Ctrl+U in Firefox)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that from the command line like:

```
$> firefox view-source:http://stackoverflow.com
```

Or you can put something like this in the URL bar: "view-source:http://stackoverflow.com"

If you happen to want to open it in a new window:

```
$> firefox -new-window view-source:http://stackoverflow.com
```

There is a [reference at mozillazine.org](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Command_line_arguments).

Comment: Btw, do u know the way to open the find toolbar? I also wondering how to get the content of the HTML document

Comment: Those tasks are a bit more technical, and I don't have a good answer off the top of my head. You can use the `System.Net.WebClient` class to easily download various things.

Comment: There is a Wikipedia entry for the [View-source URI scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/View-source_URI_scheme).